# How to POST MultipartFile with additional information in one POST request in Spring Boot and Swagger?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, multipart

**I have the following controller structure:**

```
    @PostMapping(
            value = "/whatever",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> method(@RequestBody RequestDTO dto, @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
        ...
    }
```

**Spring Boot version:** `2.3.4.RELEASE`

**I am using swagger:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Tried and failed:**

- With specifying the parameters as `@RequestBody` and `@RequestPart`, when using the two together I am getting error 415.
- If I remove any of the inputs, the request works, so I wither upload file or DTO.
- If I am using `@RequestPart` for both of them, Swagger does not display the DTO json input field.
- If the `MultipartFile` is not annotated with `@RequestPart`, the upload button does not appear.
- If both of the parameters are annotated with `@RequestParam`, the upload fails with error 415

**Question:**
How can I upload a file with additional json information via Swagger?